# Simulate stock price based on a given equation in Python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, simulation, scipy.stats

How can I generate a price time series using the following equation:

**p(t) = p0(1+A * sin(ωt +0.5η(t)))**

where **t** ranges from **0** to **1** in **1000** time steps, **p0 = 100**, **A = 0.1**, and **ω = 100**. **η(t)** is a sequence of **i.i.d Gaussian random variables** with **zero mean** and **unit variance**.

I have use the code as follows to generate price, but it seems not as required. So I need helps from the community. Thanks in advance.

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mu = 0
sigma = 1
np.random.seed(2020)

dist = norm(loc = mu,scale=sigma)
sample = dist.rvs(size = 1000)
stock_price = np.exp(sample.cumsum())
print(stock_price)
plt.plot(stock_price)
plt.xlabel("Day")
plt.ylabel("Price")
plt.title("Simulated Stock price")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I haven't missed anything, this should do the trick

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n_t = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000)
t = np.arange(0, 1, 1/1000)

p_0, A, w = 100, 0.1, 100
ts = p_0 * (1 + A * np.sin(w * t + 0.5 * n_t))

plt.plot(t, ts)
plt.xlabel("Day")
plt.ylabel("Price")
plt.show()
```

which gives the plot 
[image]

Comment: Thank you. Could you check my answer and give me feedback? It seems the result from my code seems more likes price volatility.

Comment: Hmh this line `stock_price = np.exp(sample.cumsum())` is def not quite right, you are using both np.exp and np.cumsum and neither of those is in the actual equation you posted above.

Answer (score 0):

My trial, not sure if it's correct, welcome to give me some comments.

```
import numpy as np
import math
np.random.seed(2020)

mu = 0
sigma = 1
dt = 0.01
p0 = 100
A = 0.1
w = 100
N = 1000
for t in np.linspace(0, 1, 1000):
    X = np.random.normal(mu * dt, sigma* np.sqrt(dt), N)
    X = np.cumsum(X)
    pt = p0 * (1+ A*np.sin(w*t + 0.5*X))
#     print(pt)
plt.plot(pt)
plt.xlabel("Day")
plt.ylabel("Price")
plt.title("Simulated Stock price")
plt.show()
```

Out:

[image]